# Variation of the kinetic quark term of the QCD Lagrangian under gauge transformation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, spinors

A simple kinetic quark term would look like
$$\bar{\psi}(\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu} - m){\psi}.$$
Imposing SU(3) symmetry the Dirac spinor transforms like
$$\psi(x) \rightarrow \psi'(x) = e^{ig_s \alpha(x)^aT^a}\psi(x),$$
where $T^a$ are the generators of SU(3).

Looking at the infinitesimal transformations of the kinetic term due to this transformation gives:

$$\bar{\psi}(\mathbb{1} - ig_s \alpha^aT^a)(i\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu} - m)(\mathbb{1} + ig_s\alpha^aT^a)\psi =\\
 \bar{\psi}(i\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu} - m)\psi + \bar{\psi}(i\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu} - m)ig_s \alpha^a T^a \psi + \bar{\psi}(-ig_s \alpha^a T^a)(i\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu} - m)\psi + \bar{\psi}(-ig_s\alpha^aT^a)(i\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu} - m)(ig_s \alpha^a T^a)\psi.$$

In the texbtook I'm trying to follow they then skip the calculations and arrive at:

$$ \bar{\psi}(\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu} - m)\psi=\bar{\psi}(i\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu} - m)\psi - \bar{\psi}(g_s i \gamma^{\mu} \partial_{\mu} 
\alpha^a T^a)\psi.$$

I can't seem to reproduce this result. Why do the two terms linear in $g_s$ cancel each other? To do that we would have to know that $T$ and $\gamma$ commute with each other which isn't obvious to me.
And where does the mass term of the term quadratic in $g_s$ vanish to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term quadratic in $g_s$ vanished because we are considering transformations infinitesimal in $\alpha$ here, and only linear terms are considered.

To see that $T^a$ and $\gamma^\mu$ commute with each other we can write the kinetic terms expliciting the indices:
$$ \tag{1} \bar \psi (i \gamma^\mu \partial_\mu - m ) \psi
\equiv \bar \psi_{\alpha,i} (i \gamma^\mu_{\alpha\beta} \delta_{ij} \partial_\mu - m \delta_{\alpha \beta} \delta_{ij}) \psi_{\beta,j},$$
where the $i,j$ indices are *flavour indices*, and come from the fact the spinor fields $\psi$ transform under some representation (in this case the fundamental) of the gauge group (in this case $SU(3)$).
The $\delta_{ij}$ and $\delta_{\alpha \beta}$ terms are there as the components of the identity matrices acting respectively on the gauge group and on the spin degrees of freedom.
Another way to write **(1)**, summing over the index $i$ and using the $\delta_{ij}$ term, is:
$$ \tag{1'} \bar \psi_{\alpha, j} ( i \gamma^\mu_{\alpha \beta} \partial_\mu - m \delta_{\alpha \beta}) \psi_{\beta,j} = 0. $$
The physical reason for the kinetic operator $(i \! \not\! \partial-m) $ to be diagonal on the flavour indices is that during propagation the flavour does not change (e.g. a [quark down](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Down_quark) does not decide by itself to become a [bottom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottom_quark), if not interacting with something else).
Yet another way to write **(1)**, with which you may or may not be more familiar is
$$ \tag{1''} i \bar \psi_\alpha^j \gamma^\mu_{\alpha\beta} \partial_\mu \psi_\beta^j
 - m \bar \psi_{\alpha}^j \psi_{\alpha}^j
\equiv i \bar \psi \gamma^\mu \partial_\mu \psi - m \bar \psi \psi = 0. $$

---

Expliciting the indices the gauge transformation has the form:
$$ \tag{2} \psi_{\alpha,i}(x)
\rightarrow (e^{ i g_s \alpha^a(x) T^a} )_{ij} \psi_{\alpha,j}(x),$$
which keeping only terms linear in $\alpha$ becomes:
$$ \tag{3} \psi_{\alpha,i}(x) \rightarrow ( \delta_{ij} + ig_s \alpha^a(x) T^a_{ij}) \psi_{\alpha,j}(x)
\equiv \psi_{\alpha,i}(x) + ig_s \alpha^a(x) T^a_{ij} \psi_{\alpha,j}(x),  $$
where it is important to notice how the generators $T^a$ act on the flavour indices $i,j$, *not* on the spinor indices $\alpha,\beta$.
Once you have made explicit all the sum involved in the indices, all the object you are left with are (eventually complex) numbers, hence *they all commute* (with the exception of the spinor fields of course, which are Grassman numbers.

How does this apply to your calculation?

1. Your fourth term is neglected because of order $\mathcal{O}(\alpha^2)$.
2. In your second term the derivative acts *both* on $\alpha$ and on $\psi$, giving the term (I'm no longer expliciting indices here for brevity):
   $$ \tag{4} \bar \psi ( i \gamma^\mu \partial_\mu - m) ig_s \alpha^a T^a \psi
   = -g_s (\partial_\mu \alpha^a) \bar \psi \gamma^\mu T^a \psi
   + i g_s \alpha^a \bar \psi ( i \gamma^\mu \partial_\mu - m ) T^a \psi  $$
3. The term involving both the $\gamma$ and the generators $T^a$ (and the derivative $\partial_\mu$ acting on $\psi$) has the form:
   $$ \tag{5} (i)^2g \alpha^a \bar \psi_{\alpha,i} (\gamma^\mu_{\alpha\beta} T^a_{ij} - T^a_{ij} \gamma^\mu_{\alpha\beta}) \partial_\mu \psi_{\beta,j} = 0, $$
   where as I said above $\gamma^\mu_{\alpha\beta}, T^a_{ij} \in \mathbb{C}$ hence they commute.

See also [the wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_covariant_derivative#Construction_of_the_covariant_derivative_throught_Gauge_covariance_requirement) on the gauge covariant derivative for similar calculations.

Comment: Couple of questions: 
If I simply disregard any term that is quadratic in $g_s$, then I don't get where the 2nd term in the final result comes from. When $T^a$ and $\gamma^{\mu}$ commute, then the two middle terms in the 4 term equation identically vanish, leaving with only $\bar{\psi}(i\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu} - m)\psi$ when I cancel all terms that aren't linear in $g_s$. What gives?

Also why does expliciting the indices give a Kronecker delta in both terms? This isn't trivial to me.

Comment: @user17574 see the edits. In particular, the second term in your final result comes from the second term of your second equation, where $\partial_\mu$ acts on $\alpha$. The Kronecker delta is just a way to express the fact that the operator in between $\bar \psi$ and $\psi$ does not act on flavour indices (nor on spinor indices, in the case of the mass term).

Comment: With all these indices I simlpy forgot about the product rule :) Thanks a lot for clearing up my confusion!